# Laravel 5 other routes show 404

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have been working with laravel 4 for a long time without problem and now i am depping in the laravel 5, so i found some frustrating bugs that i dont know how to fix, here the code.

route

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');// works
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@home');//dont work
//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');//still doesn't work
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{       
    return view('home');//it works      
}

public function home()
{
    return view('home');// it does not work :(
}
```

the home.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Home</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

At the browser
   http://mailing_creator.dev/   << it open the welcome page normal
   http://mailing_creator.dev/home   <<< it show 404 not found :(

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !! I just have to uncomment the

"LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so"

on apache httpd.conf, i am using wamp server and the "rewrite module" is disabled i just have to enable it and it will works